# Apc hit miss cached file, and lost diagrams in apc.php

Tags: php, apc

with Server API:    CGI/FastCGI

[image]

Apc hit miss cached file, and lost diagrams in apc.php. 
How i can make apc run perfect, do this error happen because server use CGI/FastCGi ?

Now , it cached 32MB file but miss 99% . 
**Edit:It lost digram pictur because i don't install PHP-GD library.**

Comment: What is your question?  The graphs never really rendered correctly; maybe they finally gave up on trying in a recent version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of FastCGI each PHP-process have his own APC-memory (until this process stay alive), so use memcache/d with FastCGI.

Comment: @meotimdihia What will always remain? You can't use APC as data-cacher with FastCGI. Use Memcache: http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php

Comment: uhm, but i installed apc run fine in ubuntu, it is easier a lot than Centos . And Apc is faster than Memcache when only a hosting.

Comment: well.. choose: or mod_php with APC cache, or FastCGI without.